# Reference type for SML

Tags: sml

I have two refs in SML:

val a = ref 5;
val b = ref 6;

Currently a = b evaluates to false. Is it possible to somehow assign variable b so that a = b evaluates to true?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It's not, they are pointers to different object.

Technically you could do

```
val a = ref 5;
val b = a;
```

That would work.

Comment: So once two pointers are initialized, they will always point to different object?

Comment: You could have them point to the same object via assignment but generally speaking yes, two pointers will always point to different places when initialized against different constant values.