# set a reference equal to another reference in SML

Tags: pointers, reference, functional-programming, sml

Is it possible to update a reference to equal another reference in SML? This may be a really silly question, but I can't seem to get my head around it. For example, consider the following two references:

```
val x1 = ref(NONE);
val x2 = ref(NONE);

(*update so that x1 = x2; returns true*)
```

How can I update x1 to be equal to x2. I'm not talking about putting the contents that x2 points into x1, I want to know if I can set them equal so when I test for equality (eq x1 = x2) the result is true.

I thought about having them point to a new memory location.

```
val z = NONE
x1 := z
x2 := z
```

This doesn't work. I'm guessing I should review references in SML again. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference type for SML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235507/reference-type-for-sml)

Answer (score 3):

There is no assignment to variables in ML. So two variables that start out with two different values will never be equal. `ref NONE` evaluates to the pointer to a new mutable reference object; hence two calls to `ref` will evaluate to pointers to different objects.

That it's a reference is not really relevant. It is the same with any other type:

```
val x1 = 2;
val x2 = 3;
(*update so that x1 = x2; returns true*)
```

`x1 = x2` will never be true. (At least not with that `x1` and that `x2`; if you define a new `x1`, then that's another story.)

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I know of that you can have two refs be equal is if they are the same:

```
val x1 = ref NONE
val x2 = x1
```

will cause `x1 = x2` to be true.